# Fluent Bit Java Multiline parser on docker container logs in Kubernetes cluster (via New Relic integration)

Tags: java, kubernetes, multiline, fluent-bit

We're using [New Relic Fluent Bit integration](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-fluent-bit-output/) to send Kubernetes pod logs to New Relic. Some pods are running Java apps so we'd like to apply java multiline parsing. Unfortunately this fluent-bit conf catch logs but multiline java parsing added in a FILTER block is not working. How can we do?

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: fluent-bit-config
      namespace: newrelic
      labels:
        k8s-app: newrelic-logging
    data:
      # fluent bit config file
      fluent-bit.conf: |
        [SERVICE]
            Flush             1
            Log_Level         info
            Daemon            off
            Parsers_File      parsers.conf
            HTTP_Server       On
            HTTP_Listen       0.0.0.0
            HTTP_Port         2020
    
        @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
        @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
        @INCLUDE output-newrelic.conf
    
      input-kubernetes.conf: |
        [INPUT]
            Name              tail
            Tag               kube.*
            Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
            Parser            docker
            DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
            Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
            Skip_Long_Lines   On
            Refresh_Interval  10
    
      filter-kubernetes.conf: |
        [FILTER]
            Name        record_modifier
            Match       *
            Record      cluster_name ${CLUSTER_NAME}
    
        [FILTER]
            Name        kubernetes
            Match       kube.*
            Kube_URL    https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
            Merge_Log   Off
        
        [FILTER]
            Name                  multiline
            Match                 kube.*
            multiline.key_content log
            multiline.parser      java
    
      output-newrelic.conf: |
        [OUTPUT]
            Name        newrelic
            Match       *
            licenseKey  ${LICENSE_KEY}
            endpoint    ${ENDPOINT}
      
      parsers.conf: |
        [PARSER]
            Name              docker
            Format            json
            Time_Key          time
            Time_Format       %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
            Time_Keep         On
```

Comment: any progress on getting this filter to work? i am running into a similar issue with filtering the logs and concatenating multi-line logs from a java app running in docker

Comment: didn't try to fix this, maybe I should get back to it.

Comment: the java parser does not seem to work for me, so i believe i have to use the new `MULTILINE_PARSER` to create a custom multiline parser using the regex method. have not gotten it to work yet